# "health product industry" or "health-product industry"?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I would have written "health-product industry", but Googling makes "health product industry" seem more common. I thought that if we created a compound adjective ("health-product" describing "industry"), we should hyphenate. But I also see stuff like "sports equipment industry", unhyphenated.

Should I be hyphenating here?

Comment: I don't think so -- that seems to be a general rule, focusing on prefixes being prepended, but this specific example didn't seem to be clarified with that link.

Comment: With individual cases, which _may_ buck trends, the obvious way to go is to research using ngrams or raw Google data. But I don't think a reasonable person is going to find fault with either _health-product industry_ or _health product industry_. The 'rules' are rules of thumb anyway, the hyphen here is not needed to disambiguate say, and the modern move is to minimise hyphen usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pluralise ***products*** and lose the hyphen...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=health%20product%20industry%2Chealth-product%20industry%2Chealth%20products%20industry&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image]

(The hyphenated version doesn't occur often enough to show on the chart.)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that some writing guides advise hyphenation to clarify compound adjectives. That said, the hyphenation is often a guideline rather than a required practice, since in many cases the resulting phrase (*health product industry*, *electric power industry*) won't be misread.

For instance, [APA](https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen) acknowledges that many compounds don't need to be hyphenated:

> In a temporary compound that is used as an adjective before a noun, use a hyphen if the term can be misread or if the term expresses a single thought (i.e., all words together modify the noun).

A temporary compound might be a nonce-formation used for a specific statement. In that case, the hyphenation would aid in preventing misreading:

- two-parent homes (distinguishes from two parent homes, that is, two homes)

However, since "health product" and "sports equipment" are well-known compounds, hyphenating them is not necessary.